# Serilog separate rolling files for each SourceContext

Tags: serilog

this is my serilog configuration :

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.RollingFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                     @"Logs\log-{Date}.txt"))
.MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LogLevelSwitch)
.CreateLogger();
```

i'm logging like this :

```
var log = Serilog.Log.ForContext<SomeClassName>();
log.Information("some log text");
```

**My question :**

I need a modification in my configuration to create separate logs for each SourceContext.

I need log files somthing like `Logs\log-{Date}-{SourceContext}.txt`

thanks pros...

Answer (score 3):

One way to implement this is to create your own `ILogEventSink` implementation (the interface is very simple) that internally dispatches to one of several `RollingFileSink`s based on the `SourceContext` property of the `LogEvent`.

To configure it (let's say you call your sink `SourceRollingFileSink`) you can use `WriteTo.Sink()`:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.Sink(new SourceRollingFileSink())
  .CreateLogger();
```

There's no out-of-the-box implementation so some work is required, but it should not be complicated. **Be aware** that implementations of `ILogEventSink` need to be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try